# How to list all files and its datetime in Unix?

Tags: file, datetime, unix

I'm a beginner in Unix.
My question is simple:

How could I list only the files with its date time?

```
     find /risk/local_z -type f
```

Thanks all.

Comment: Yes of course but I need the datetime and only the datetime to have a clean result if possible :)

Comment: `find /risk/local_z -type f -exec ls -l {} \;` Then read `ls` manual to control what to display